# ASP.NET MVC vs. Jquery/AJAX (Where to draw the dividing line?)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, testing

I am learning MVC and I understand the basics now. It is very good for CRUD pages and has built in HTTP methods to post/get edits/updates. That is nice. This is all very testable by just creating a new controller and testing it.

But I was thinking about other web page scenerios when using MVC. What about a page that has 2 listboxes that you add/remove users with. (A button will move the user from one listbox to another)

This would be done using Jquery/Javascript... But then what happens to testing? How do you test adding/removing users from a listbox like that example?

It seems to me the more jquery you use the less testable the page becomes right? When you get beyond basic forms being filled out then you need to use something more than the standard MVC pages.

What is the correct philosophy on this on when am I not understanding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. adding/removing users can't be done with jQuery alone, unless your users database is local to the client browser. at some point you will have to invoke a controller action in the MVC application to persist the choice. that action is unit testable.
2. there are fameworks and techniques for unit testing JavaScript that you can use to unit test your jQery code.

The right way to think about this scenario is to separate your application into two - one server MVC app and a client side jQuery app. The fact that the client-side code is generated and delivered by the server side app actions and views is irrelevant.

Once you start separating these two, you can start thinking about how to unit test each of them properly.

Comment: But what if I did not want to commit the changes until I clicked a SAVE button.. therefore Id have to track the changes in some javascript object... I am not familiar with javscript unit testing? What is the official MS tool to do this? I have never heard of i

Yes, it seems to me the best way is to go back to the server everytime a button is clicked.. so you can continue to have a MVC testable app.. I understand now I think.

Comment: What if my SAVE button calls a AJAX method ?  Does that break the MVC model... or is there no difference between using AJAX to call a method or postback because they call the same method (whereas one is tagged with some sort of ajax attribute)

Do I got it right?

Comment: Using Ajax to post back does not break the MVC model. You are still posting back to a particular URL, which is backed by an action on a particular controller. The only difference is that this action might not return a View result, but might return an XML or a File result for example (or even an empty result).

Comment: There is no "official" Microsoft JS unit testing framework (at least as far as I know). The "de facto official JQuery unit testing framewokr (what most people use) is QUnit (http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit). There are other framework out there as well like JsUnit (http://jsunit.net) for example - http://www.bing.com/search?q=javascript+unit+testing yields a lot of results (or search using your favorite search engine).

Answer (score 1):

Progressive enhancement: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/

Make *everything* works without jQuery/Ajax, using regular HTML. Plain old links and submits.

Then, let jQ be a very thin layer on top. For me, I just have jQ [submit forms via Ajax](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) instead of the regular submit. Same form, same controller, it just happens without the full page refresh.

Doing it this way means that jQ's only real responsibility is UI refinement. If it fails, it falls back to regular HTML.

So front-end testing becomes a bit less important -- you are assured of correct functionality, you're just testing for UI niceties.

Comment: This is a quite mature response. Every ASP.NET MVC newbie must read this before jumping into dev. +1